# Create a list of repeated elements from 2 lists in python

Tags: python

Being new to python, here is my problem. Given two lists:

```
a = [3, 4] 
b = [5, 2]
```

I want to create a new list which consists of items of first list repeated n number of times, where n is the corresponding element in second list.  So I would like an output like:

```
c = [3,3,3,3,3,4,4]
```

Where 3 is repeated 5 times, 4 is repeated 2 times and so on.
My current code looks like this

```
for item,no in zip(a,b):
    print(str(item)*no)
```

which gets me:

```
33333
44
```

I am trying to figure out how to get from my current stage to the output that I want. Any help would be appreciated.

I was also thinking that maybe this could be done with list comprehension but I could not come up with the python code for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like this:

```
[i for i,j in zip(a, b) for k in range(j)]
```

The above line is equivalent to the following nested for loops:

```
c = []
for i,j in zip(a, b):
    for k in range(j):
        c.append(i)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> a = [3, 4]
>>> b = [5, 2]
>>> c = [i for i,j in zip(a, b) for k in range(j)]
>>> c
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4]
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation. I am not very confident with nested comprehensions yet. I had the intuition that it could be done, but was struggling to figure it out.

Comment: You're welcome! In all cases you have list comprehension and the equivalent code with for loops, so you need just to choose the one that you prefer ;)

Comment: Yea, I ended up using the comprehension while using the dual for loop code in order to get my head around nested comprehensions.

Answer (score 2):

A simple list comprehension would work:

```
>>> a = [3, 4]
>>> b = [5, 2]
>>> [c for n, m in zip(a, b) for c in [n]*m]
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4]
```

If you are concerned on the memory efficiency (e.g. for large `m`) then you can use `itertools.repeat()` to avoid the intermediate lists:

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> [c for n, m in zip(a, b) for c in it.repeat(n, m)]
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That makes sense. I am still learning python so was not very confident about using the zip method. Also I am still not very good with list comprehensions which contain nested comprehensions.

Answer (score 0):

```
c=[]
for item, count in zip(a,b):
    c.extend([item]*count)
print(c)
```

should do it.  Add to the list one element at a time, and then print all at once at the end.  `[item]*count` is a `count`-element list(`[]`) of `item`, and [`extend`](http://edumaven.com/python-programming/list-append-vs-extend) adds the *contents* of the list you provide to the list you call `extend` on.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use extend

```
c = []
for item, no in zip(a, b):
    c.extend([item] * no)
```

Comment: thanks, that's the easiest answer I can quickly understand. I did not know that [ ] * no would work.

Answer (score 0):

You said you were new to Python, so here's a simple way to do it, just using basic loops:

```
a = [3 , 4]
b = [5 , 2]
c = []
index = 0
for i in a:
     for i in range(0 , b[index]):
         c.append(i)
     index += 1
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah coming from more of a JAVA background I could get the logic for using loops with indexes but if I am not wrong(I probably am) that is not the preferred way in python. That was the reason for my struggles. Also the fact that I could do something like [ ]  * n to get a longer list with repeated elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
c = []
for i in range(len(b)):
    for j in range(b[i]):
        c.append(a[i])
print c
```

Answer (score 0):

Something a bit different

```
c = [a[b.index(j)] for i,j in enumerate(b) for i in range(j)]
```